# In an AndroidManfiest.xml file, what is the impact of renaming/moving/removing activities?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Many/most of the settings in AndroidManifest.xml have a public impact. Changing the package name changes the identity of the app in the store. Changing uses-permission changes the list of permissions and may prevent automatic updates, etc.

What is the impact of removing or renaming a non-MAIN activity? For that matter, what is the impact of renaming the MAIN activity? Given that the intent-filter is used to mark it main I'm not sure why changes to the name or package of the MAIN activity would matter.

It's apparently necessary that all activity classes be declared here, so I want to know if I'll cause some sort of public effect simply by refactoring an activity so it has a different name or package.

The developer page for AndroidManifest.xml doesn't get into public consequences of changes. Can someone point me to a page describing the impacts of various changes to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at an official blog post by the Android team here: [Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor the name of your refactor the name of some Activity, either in the Manifest or in your class, obviously both the manifest and the class have to match, otherwise you'll get errors. But, in terms of your app in the Marketplace, refactor class names has zero effect.